# J syntax for functions and modulo

Tags: function, syntax, modulo, j

I'm trying to make a function `mod3` that returns the input modulo three, but my syntax is wrong. I don't see why the syntax would be any different from the `double` example in the docs.

```
$ jconsole
   double =: * & 2
   double 1
2
   double 2
4
   double 3
6
   mod3 =: 3 | &
|syntax error
|   mod3=:    3|&
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `&` (bond) is used to bind a noun to a verb it is essentially creating a new verb with a "fixed" left (or right) argument. Because multiplication is commutative it doesn't matter whether you fix the `2` as the left or right argument so the following are equivalent:

```
   double1= *&2     NB. new verb "times by 2"
   double2=: 2&*    NB. new verb "2 times"
   double1 4
8
   double2 4
8
```

However residule (`|`) is not commutative so in your case you must make sure you fix/bond (the `3` as the left argument of `|` to get the desired result (the remainder of a number divided by 3).

```
   modulo3=: 3&|    NB. new verb "remainder after divison by 3"
   modulox=: |&3    NB. new verb "remainder of 3 divided by"
   modulo3 7
1
   modulox 7
3
```

Comment: If `|` takes a left argument and a right argument, why does infix `3 | 2` work by itself, but when defining functions you have to use postix `3 & |`? It's inconsistent.

Comment: To be honest I'm struggling to understand what you are finding unclear. I suspect that you are expecting J to fit some non-J syntax rules and that is preventing you from understanding J's paradigm. We need to specify the left argument we want `|` to use so we use the conjunction `&` to bind the left argument to it. Another method would be to use a fork and define `mod3=: 3 | ]`

Comment: I should add that the reason I'm struggling to understand your point of view is that my experience with the prefix/postfix/infix terminology is limited. Can you explain why `3 & |` is "postfix"? Couldn't you argue that from the point of view of the conjunction `&`, the statement is infix?

Comment: Infix: `1 + 2`. Prefix: `+ 1 2`. Postfix: `1 2 +`. When using the modulo function outside of a function declaration, you use infix: `3 | 4`. But when you use modulo inside a function declaration, you must use either prefix `| & 3` or postfix `3 & |`. Based on Wikipedia's description of APL's left-to-right order of operations, I expected J to not even have infix ("dyad") functions, only prefix functions, like Lisp has.

Comment: I don't see `3&|` as being postfix. Once this verb is executed it becomes `3&| 7`. You can probably argue that this is prefix (the verb `3&|` is before the `7`) or perhaps even infix if you see that the | is between the 3 and the 7. However I think J is in principle infix - it's all about working out the right (or left and right) argument(s) for a verb. But verbs in a J sentence are executed from right to left.

Comment: "But verbs in a J sentence are executed from right to left."

That's the confusing part.

Comment: It is true that verbs in a J sentence are executed right to left. It is also the case that modifiers are executed left to right. In addition, infix can be considered the central J form, with prefix being the single-argument exception for verbs, and postfix being the single-argument exception for modifiers. Since `&` is a modifier, `3&|` is an infix phrasing of a verb. It is not a postfix use of the verb `|`, as `|` is a parameter to `&` . The entire verb that results from `3&|` takes an argument (such as 7) to its right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why J, a predominately prefix language, uses this syntax, but the mailing list says to use this version, and it works.

```
mod3 =: 3 & |
```

Answer (score 0):

The point, as I see it, is that when you have a dyadic verb, and you bond an argument to it, it becomes a monadic verb.  Monadic verbs always have their argument as a y (J terminology) or, on the right.

Example: 
       ^&3] 4
    64
 The ] separates the 3 4 so that they are not seen as a single number. I started with a dyadic verb, power, take x to the y power. By adding the bind, I have created a monadic verb that has, as it's definition, take y to the third power.

```
    3&^ 4
81
```

This is essentially the same example, except that now my monadic verb is "take 3 to the y power".

What the double example (more succinct as +:) was trying to show was exactly what we are showing:  That a dyadic verb which is converted into a monadic verb with bond always takes the single argument it needs to execute as a right argument, no matter which side the first argument is bonded to.

What it does not show is that for verbs which are not commutative, it matters which side you bind the original argument to.  But now you know. :-)